# Simple way to reconstruct 2D graphs into 3D with +1 variable dimension

Tags: r

I am new to R and only know how to use few libraries.
I can easily use it in this format:
`mygraph = function1(x, y, specifications...)`

But its only in 2D features.
Is there a way to simply add another dimension of variable by using another library?
Such as:
`function2(mygraph, variable3)`

Or is it the most simplest way in overall?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is unclear. Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, preferably in the context of a reproducible example.

Comment: Okay lets say i use `library(whateverplot)` and from the `data`, i use 2 variables, for example, `Age` and `Income` for the graph and 2 more, `Region` and `Populationtotal`, for settings, like this: `mygraph=whateverplot(Age, Income, data=data, colby=Region, sizeby=Populationtotal)` etc.    
But as you can see its a 2D graph, and I don't know what to do when I should add another `variable` into the Z-dimension, lets say `Infantmortality`.

Comment: Basically, I am making a graph that the points are proportional to population size and colored by region, and also want it to be visualized with Years on Z-dimension, so instead of proportional circles, there will be proportional spheres, behaving how X/Y change for the duration of Z.

Comment: If you are asking if there are R packages for 3-D graphing then the answer is "yes, several such packages". Just Google "R 3-D plotting" and pick one. If you are asking if there is a package which will automatically convert arbitrary 2-D graphs to 3-D graphs, I don't think so. In any event, asking for library recommendations is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't know it was off-topic, sorry, and thank you for your help.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/3d-plots-with-ggplot2-and-plotly/) might help. You can find other r-bloggers posts which discuss other ways to do 3-d plotting. I am not in 100% agreement that making library recommendations should be off-topic (item 4 in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) but I don't set the rules. If you decide on a specific library and then have trouble using it, it would be on-topic to then ask for help.